# IOS 8 Dynamic Type with Static TableView Cell - Basic and Subtitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

After changing the text size in settings and returning to the application, static cells of type Basic and Subtitle and left blank until you move away from the view or reload the app. A Custom static cell retains its text.

Simple to replicate.

Create a single view app, replace the UIViewController with a UiTableViewController.
Change the Content from Dynamic to Static Cells.

Set Style cell 0 = Custom, cell 1 = Basic and cell 2 = Subtitle

Hook up properties for all

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *customCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *basicCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *subTitleLabel;
```

add the following to viewDidLoad

```
NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateInterfaceForDynamicTypeSize)      name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];


self.customCell.text = @"Custom Cell";
self.basicCell.text = @"Basic Cell";
self.titleLabel.text = @"My Title";
self.subTitleLabel.text = @"My Sub Title";
```

add the following method

```
-(void)updateInterfaceForDynamicTypeSize {
UIFont *font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
self.customCell.font = font;
self.basicCell.font = font;
self.titleLabel.font = font;
font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleFootnote];
self.subTitleLabel.font = font;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Run the app - then go to Settings and change the text size.
Return to the app and only the Custom cell content is displayed.

This was not the case with IOS 7. Am I missing something here or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Configure your cell in storyboard to use the custom class instead of default `UITableViewCell`

Simple custom cell implement as follow:

```c
// DynamicTypeResistantCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DynamicTypeResistantCell : UITableViewCell

@end


// DynamicTypeResistantCell.m
@implementation DynamicTypeResistantCell
- (void)_systemTextSizeChanged
{
    // don't call super!
}
@end
```

Then you can safely use the Basic and Subtitle styles and cell preserve their content after dynamic type size changes.